# CSRF token is invalid when calling rest post api from php Client

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I have created a rest api in Symfony. It uses form for the client to send the data.
I have used 'csrf_protection' => false in setDefaultOptions, but still getting the error

The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form

Answer (score 0):

Did you test your api over [NelmioApiDocBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle) sanbox, or your sending data from form on frontned side? Are you sure that your not sending csrf_protection requsest parameter to your api?

Comment: I am calling api from php using curl and 100% sure that csrf_protection is not sent. Here is the sample code for client

$curl_post_data =  json_encode($curl_post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);