# FOSRestBundle & invalid form CRF token

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to implement FOSRestBundle and Symfony forms.
I have found this [tutorial](http://welcometothebundle.com/web-api-rest-with-symfony2-the-best-way-the-post-method/) but I have problem with [this](https://github.com/liuggio/symfony2-rest-api-the-best-2013-way/blob/master/src/Acme/BlogBundle/Handler/PageHandler.php#L106) part

```
private function processForm(PageInterface $page, array $parameters, $method = "PUT")
{
    $form = $this->formFactory->create(new PageType(), $page, array('method' => $method));
    $form->submit($parameters, 'PATCH' !== $method);
    if ($form->isValid()) { //form is not valid.
        $page = $form->getData();
        $this->om->persist($page);
        $this->om->flush($page);
        return $page;
    }
    throw new InvalidFormException('Invalid submitted data', $form);
}
```

> ERROR: The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.

[Here](https://github.com/liuggio/symfony2-rest-api-the-best-2013-way/blob/master/src/Acme/BlogBundle/Controller/PageController.php#L127) is the controller from tutorial. And here is my class controller:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{

    $form = new EntryType();
    $newEntry = $this->container->get('entries.entry.handler')->post(
        $request->request->get($form->getName())
    );

    return View::create()
        ->setStatusCode(200)
        ->setFormat('json')
        ->setSerializationContext(SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('list')))
        ->setData($newEntry);
}
```

Should I skip checking `isValid()` or fix this somehow? How?

---

OK, It is clear now. CRF verification (csrf_protection) should be disabled

[CSRF token is invalid when calling rest post api from php Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344272/csrf-token-is-invalid-when-calling-rest-post-api-from-php-client)
https://github.com/liuggio/symfony2-rest-api-the-best-2013-way/issues/1#issuecomment-31435232
[CSRF validation needed or not when using RESTful API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220655/csrf-validation-needed-or-not-when-using-restful-api)

Comment: how do you render the form ?

Comment: I don't. I want to add new record via API. Please check my updated question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony - CSRF token is invalid - FosRestBundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461760/symfony-csrf-token-is-invalid-fosrestbundle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From part 3 of the [tutorial](http://welcometothebundle.com/symfony2-rest-api-the-best-way-part-3/#disable_csrf_with_rest) :

> It's possible to disable the CSRF based on the user’s role.

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_rest:
    disable_csrf_role: ROLE_API
    # you can also try
    # disable_csrf_role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY
```

See also this [issue](https://github.com/liuggio/symfony2-rest-api-the-best-2013-way/issues/1).